# How to get sum of all records in another column in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I want to display all the sum of a particular columns in another column with out changing the origianl quantites. Below is my table.

My Original batch_request table

```
   +----------+-------------+
    | order_id | Ordertype |
    +----------+------------+
    | 31234567 |         A1 |
    | 5xyzsder |         A1 |
    | 8DQVIHSC |         A1 | 
    | xyz123   |         B2 |
    | t123     |         B2 |
    +----------+-------------+
```

Original reports_ref table

```
+----------+---------------+---------------+
| order_id | SUBMITTED_QTY | STOCK_ID      |
+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 31234567 |          3.00 | 4032611179505 |
| 5xyzsder |          3.00 | 4032611179505 |
| 8DQVIHSC |          4.00 | 4032611179505 |
| xyz123   |          5.00 | 4032611179505 |
| t123     |          15.00| 4032611179505 |  
+----------+---------------+---------------+
```

What i am getting with my query

```
+----------+---------------+---------------+
| order_id | SUBMITTED_QTY | STOCK_ID      |
+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 31234567 |          3.00 | 4032611179505 |
| 5xyzsder |          3.00 | 4032611179505 |
| 8DQVIHSC |          4.00 | 4032611179505 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+
```

My desired out put will be like this.

```
    +----------+---------------+---------------+------+
    | order_id | SUBMITTED_QTY | STOCK_ID      |Total |
    +----------+---------------+---------------+------+
    | 31234567 |          3.00 | 4032611179505 |10.00 |
    | 5xyzsder |          3.00 | 4032611179505 |10.00 |
    | 8DQVIHSC |          4.00 | 4032611179505 |10.00 |
    +----------+---------------+---------------+------+
   For this  my query is
```

```
SELECT ref.order_id,SUM(ref.SUBMITTED_QTY) SUBMITTED_QTY, ref.STOCK_ID 
        FROM batch_request bo 
        JOIN reports_ref ref ON bo.order_id = ref.order_id WHERE ref.STOCK_ID = '4032611179505'
```

But i am getting this out put.How to achieve my desired output?

```
    +----------+---------------+---------------+
    | order_id | SUBMITTED_QTY | STOCK_ID      |
    +----------+---------------+---------------+
    | 31234567 |          10.00| 4032611179505 |
    +----------+---------------+---------------+
```

How to achieve my desired output? any one please suggest me where i am doing wrong?

**This is an original query**

```
    SELECT ref.order_id,
       SUM(ref.SUBMITTED_QTY) SUBMITTED_QTY, 
       ref.STOCK_ID 
    FROM batch_request bo 
    JOIN reports_ref ref 
    ON bo.order_id = ref.order_id 
    WHERE ref.STOCK_ID = '4032611179505' 
      AND bo.order_type = 'A1' 
      AND DATE(ref.inserted_on) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-03-02'
```

Comment: Alex i tried with your query by adding the other table as join .SELECT ref.order_id,ref.SUBMITTED_QTY, ref.STOCK_ID ,
    t.total
FROM reports_ref ref
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
       order_id,
       SUM(SUBMITTED_QTY) AS total
    FROM reports_ref
    GROUP BY order_id
) AS t
ON t.STOCK_ID = ref.STOCK_ID
JOIN batch_request bo ON bo.`order_id` = ref.`order_id`
AND bo.order_type = 'PRE_ORDER' AND DATE(`inserted_on`) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-03-02'
WHERE ref.STOCK_ID = '4032611179505' . But i am getting total count 12 instead of 10 in all the 3 rows. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ref.order_id,ref.SUBMITTED_QTY, ref.STOCK_ID ,
    t.total
FROM reports_ref ref
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT order_id
  FROM batch_request
  WHERE order_type = 'A1' 
) as bo  
ON bo.order_id = ref.order_id 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
       STOCK_ID,
       SUM(SUBMITTED_QTY) as total
    FROM reports_ref
    WHERE STOCK_ID = '4032611179505'
    GROUP BY STOCK_ID
) AS t
ON t.STOCK_ID = ref.STOCK_ID
WHERE ref.STOCK_ID = '4032611179505'
  AND DATE(ref.inserted_on) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-03-02'
```

Comment: where is all comments?

Comment: even I don't know , Any way thanks for the solution.

Comment: Hi Alex, can you please check this link--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398193/adding-multiple-conditions-to-check-whether-columns-are-empty-or-not-in-mysql-ca?noredirect=1#comment46973362_29398193

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SELECT ref.order_id, ref.SUBMITTED_QTY, ref.STOCK_ID, SUM(ref.SUBMITTED_QTY) as Total FROM reports_ref as ref JOIN batch_requests as bo ON bo.order_id = ref.order_id WHERE ref.STOCK_ID = '4032611179505';

Comment: No, i want to return all the 3 rows with additional column Total with 10.I mean i want to display total 10 in all the 3 rows.

Comment: Yes, the SQL above should return to you all the rows that match your stock_id in the reports_ref table. It will then create an output with 4 columns (order_id, SUBMITTED_QTY, STOCK_ID, Total) and we defined Total as the sum of SUBMITTED_QTY.

Comment: But i am getting only one row with order_id, SUBMITTED_QTY, STOCK_ID, Total

Comment: Is there one entry in batch_requests for every entry in reports_ref for the join to return all of the rows you want?

Comment: Yes, in batch_requests i have only order_id, and the related stock_ids,submitted_qty will sit in the reprots_ref,

Comment: Can you tell me what the single row my query returns looks like? Is it just the first row in your example: | 31234567 |          3.00 | 4032611179505 |10.00 |

Comment: No, the last row i am getting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72361/discussion-between-saman-and-user3408779).