# How to check multiple columns whether they are empty or not using mysql case

Tags: mysql, switch-statement, case, conditional-statements

I have a table called `purchase_hs` and I have different types of level dates and different types of transport modes and quantity like below. Now my requirement is I need to consider only one level date column per row. Suppose if we have `level1` and remaining all are empty then we need to add 28 days based on the transport mode (`sea`= 28days , `air`=14 days , `truck` = 5 days and `transport mode` is empty then 28 days) and display the `level1` date quantity. If we have `level1` date and `level2` date and remaining all are empty then need to take `level2` date quantity, if we have `level1`, `level2`, and `level3` dates and `level4` ,`level5` are empty then we need to take level3 quantity  and so on. For `level4` and `level5` dates we don't need to add any days based on transport. We need to consider transport mode only for `level1`,`level2` and `level3` dates. To achieve this below is my query, but it not working.

```
SELECT level1,
    level2,
    level3,
    level4,
    level5,
    trasprt Quantity,
    CASE 
        WHEN level1 != ''
            AND level2 = ''
            AND level3 = ''
            AND level4 = ''
            AND level5 = ''
            AND trasprt = 'SEA'
            THEN DATE_ADD(level1, INTERVAL 28 DAY) level1
        WHEN level1 != ''
            AND level2 != ''
            AND level3 = ''
            AND level4 = ''
            AND level5 = ''
            AND trasprt = 'AIR'
            THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level2, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 14 DAY) level2
        WHEN level1 != ''
            AND level2 != ''
            AND level3 != ''
            AND level4 = ''
            AND level5 = ''
            AND trasprt = 'TRK'
            THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level3, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 5 DAY) level3
        WHEN level1 != ''
            AND level2 != ''
            AND level3 != ''
            AND level4 != ''
            AND level5 = ''
            THEN level4
        WHEN level1 != ''
            AND level2 != ''
            AND level3 != ''
            AND level4 != ''
            AND level5 != ''
            THEN level5
        ELSE
        END
FROM purchase_hs where stock_id = '4046228100449'
```

Table:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+----------+----------------+---------------+
| level1     | level2     | level3     | level4     | level5 | Stock Qty | transport |        StockId|
+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+----------+----------------+---------------+
| 2015-01-17 | 15.04.2015 |            |            |        | 150.0000 | SEA            | 4046228100449 |
| 2015-02-17 | 20.01.2015 | 17.02.2015 |            |        | 150.0000 | SEA            | 4046228100450 |
| 2015-01-15 | 05.04.2015 | 05.04.2015 | 03.05.2015 |        |   2.0000 |                | 4046228100451 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+----------+----------------+---------------+
```

My Result table would be :If i have only level1 and level2 dates and transport mode is SEA (need to add 28 days to resulting level date)then the result would be

```
+------------+----------+---------------+
| level2     | StockQty | StockId       |
+------------+----------+---------------+
| 13.05.2015 | 150.0000 | 4046228100449 |
+------------+----------+---------------+
```

If i have only level1 date and remaining all level dates are emtpy and transport mode is AIR (need to add 14 days to resulting level date) then the result would be

```
+------------+----------+---------------+
| level1     | menge_pe | ean           |
+------------+----------+---------------+
| 2015-01-31 | 150.0000 | 4046228100449 |
+------------+----------+---------------+
```

If i have only level1 date, level2 date, level3 date and level4,level5 are empty then transport mode is TRK (need to add 5 days to resulting level date) then the result would be

```
+------------+----------+---------------+
| level3     | menge_pe | ean           |
+------------+----------+---------------+
| 22.02.2015 | 150.0000 | 4046228100449 |
+------------+----------+---------------+
```

If i have only level1 date, level2 date, level3 date and level4 are having values and level5 is (we don't need to consider 28/14/5 days based on transport mode for level4 and level5 dates) then the result would be

```
+------------+----------+---------------+
| level4     | menge_pe | ean           |
+------------+----------+---------------+
| 03.05.2015 | 150.0000 | 4046228100449 |
+------------+----------+---------------+
```

So can any one please  guide me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: HI, can you please guide me in this regard? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps, instead `=''` and `!=''` you should use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: IS NULL and IS NOT NULL not working for me..

Comment: is ti your table? in your post? could you present your expected result table?

Comment: @user3408779  you have wrong imagination about relation between source data and expected result. source data - that is example of your table s at some moment, and expected result is ONE table result was get but some query. you can't provide 4 expected results for ONE source table. So if you need 4 results, you need to provide 4 source tables. If you need 1 result table with 4 records - show that as ONE table with 4 records. But the way you asked now is completely confusing.

Comment: Hi,sorry to confuse you. what i mean to say is , from the same table if we have different level dates scenarios. Just i have provided some example with level dates.I am not expecting/asking all the 4 results at a time. I am asking how to manage that with case/ when conditions.You can take any single row from source table.